# Add CSS class to view image_field in twig

Tags: views, theming

In my custom view fields twig file `views-view-fields--search--product_result.html.twig` I try to theme my view item.

```
{{ fields.field_images.content }}
<h5 class="card-title">{{ fields.title.content }}</h5>
```

How do I add a CSS class to my image field `{{ fields.field_images.content }}`?

Comment: In a Views field(s) template you can't theme field content anymore because it has already been rendered.

Comment: @4k4 Ok so what's the solution. Traditional way through Views ui and rewrite fields content?

Comment: Yes, before you rewrite the field try to add the CSS class in Style Settings of the field.

Comment: @4k4 I think it's not possible for a field which is Exclude from display? I tried but it's stripped...

Comment: OK, when you exclude from display and use field tokens you have total control over the markup and you don't need the Style Settings anymore.

Comment: Yes but then I cannot add a class to the image field... Only e.g. a wrapper element around the image field, but that's not what I need...

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: It's a preprocess function in the .theme file. I wish there was a way to do this directly into the template. This would apply that class everywhere the field appears.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_field().
 * Adds a class to a People image.
 */
function themename_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_machine_name') {
    foreach($vars['items'] as $key => $item){
      $vars['items'][ $key ]['content']['#item_attributes']['class'][] = 'my_class';
    }
  }
}
```

`themename`, `field_machine_name`, and `my_class` are placeholders for your values.

This produces:

```
<img class="my_class" src="/your/image/location.png" alt="Your alt text." typeof="foaf:Image" width="458" height="354">
```